# Application crashes when it trying to display Toast

Tags: java, android, static, crash, toast

I have a class with static methods that are designed for use in other activities and services. These methods must show Toasts and update objects for any activities.

```
package com.app.myapp;    
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;    
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.List;    
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;    
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;    
import org.apache.http.ParseException;    
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;    
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;    
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;    
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;    
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;    
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;    
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;    
import org.json.JSONException;    
import org.json.JSONObject;      
import android.content.Context;    
import android.util.Log;    
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Wall {

    private static final String TAG_Send_Error = "Send_error";
    static String res;

    public Wall() {

    }

    public static void Post(final String owner_id, final String message,
            final String access_token) {
        res = "";

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("owner_id", owner_id));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message
                        + Constants.addtext));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("v", Constants.API_VERSION));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", access_token));
                UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = null;
                try {
                    entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8");
                    Log.d("send", "start message sending");
                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(Constants.API_URI
                            + "wall.post");
                    request.setEntity(entity);// 
                    Log.d("send", "start message sending 1");
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    Log.d("send", "start message sending 2");
                    HttpResponse response = null;
                    response = client.execute(request);
                    Log.d("send", "start message sending 3");
                    HttpEntity entry = response.getEntity();
                    Log.d("send", "start message sending 4");
                    String responseText = null;
                    responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entry);
                    Log.d("send", responseText.toString());
                    JSONObject json = null;
                    json = new JSONObject(responseText);
                    if (json.has("error")) {
                        json = json.getJSONObject("error");
                        int err = json.getInt("error_code");
                        switch (err) {
                        case 0 - 15:
                            res = json.getString("error_msg");
                            break;
                        case 16:

                            break;
                        case 17:

                            break;
                        case 100:
                            res = "Invalid number of papams";
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        res = "OK";
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_Send_Error, e.toString());
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG_Send_Error, e1.toString());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_Send_Error, e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_Send_Error, e.toString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_Send_Error, e.toString());
                }
                // Toast.makeText(context, res, 3).show();
            // return res;
            }

        });
    }
 }
```

The Activity class:

```
    package com.app.myapp;    
    import android.app.Activity;    
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;    
    import android.os.Bundle;    
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;    
    import android.util.Log;    
    import android.view.View;    
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    
    import android.widget.Button;    
    import android.widget.EditText;    
    import android.widget.RadioButton;    
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SendTestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        private EditText id_edit, txtedit;
        private RadioButton sms_btn, wall_btn;
        private Button sendbtn;

        SharedPreferences prf;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_test);

            prf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            id_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Send_a_id);
            txtedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Send_A_text);
            sms_btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Send_A_sms);
            wall_btn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Send_A_wall);
            sendbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Send_A_sendbtn);
            sendbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            prf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.Send_A_sendbtn:

                if (sms_btn.isChecked()) {

                }
                if (wall_btn.isChecked()) {
                    Log.d("MY", "Отправка записи на стену");
                    Wall.Post(getApplicationContext(),
                                      id_edit.getText().toString(), txtedit.getText()
                        .toString(), prf.getString("access_token", ""));
                }
                txtedit.setText("");
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok", 3)
                        //.show();
                break;
            case R.id.Send_A_sms:

                break;
            case R.id.Send_A_wall:

                break;
            }
        }
  }
```

I need an universal method that works in own thread and that I can call from anywhere. This method must be able to change objects on the activity that call it and show toasts.
How I can solve my problem? ASyncTask?

Comment: What if you pass SendTestActivity.this as context to the Toast? Otherwise please post LogCat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julia Hexen, your solution has not results, application also crash.

I had solved my problem. Before create a new thread I was created Handler:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        // здесь все обращения к интерфейсу
        Toast.makeText(context, res, 3).show();
    }
};
```

Finally, in the end of the code of a new thread I call method:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```